# Best way to hang a server rack in the attic

Tags: attic, mounting

I am building a little home network, and bought a 6U server rack.
Right now, it's sitting in the attic, and I am trying to think how to best hang it up.

I am pretty new to this, and I am bit concerned about drilling anything in attic, as not to compromise the integrity of the structure.

The weight of the rack is about 20KG, currently. I am thinking it will be around 50-70 KG a few years down the line, as I add more stuff.

Any recommendations how to best hang it in, based on the picture below?
I can provide more pictures if below doesn't make sense.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'd be a bit concerned about cooling in the attic. Attics get hot because heat rises, and in the summer they get even hotter because no air conditioning and (usually) minimal ventilation. Servers generate heat, and are sensitive to overheating.

Comment: I can confirm issues with cooling in the attic. it will get too hot. Also it gets annoying rather quickly to clime up there. And that was my experience with just one server.

Comment: I have researched this issue a lot, and heat/cold will not be a problem for me. First of all, I am in a very mild climate country. Then, my attic is "conversion ready". So I will be converting it into a room at a later date, which will make the issue even less of a problem

Comment: Attics don't get hot because heat rises. For one thing, it doesn't. Heated _air_ rises, and that's not a factor here. They get hot because they're immediately adjacent to a huge, scalding asphalt heat sink. Even in mild climates it'll be 100 degrees up there at times. It'll also potentially be very humid. Maybe if it was insulated (with proper roof ventilation)....

Comment: Why does it need to be _hung_? Can't you put legs on it? It's hard to answer this question without a photo or a link. We have no idea how it mounts.

Comment: There was a link, looks like you edited the picture in. It's a bog-standard wall mount rack by appearances, typically 4 holes in the back of it for mounting to the wall.

Comment: I wouldn’t believe anything about attic temperature until I left a data-logger up there for a summer and winter. *I note the insulation is **below** the attic...*

Answer (score 4):

Last place I'd put one, as a network/wiring pro. Basements (off the floor/above flood levels) are good, attics not so much, and anywhere you plan to inhabit is usually a poor choice (the noise gets very tedious very quickly.) Thus, an attic that you think will be cool enough because you'll convert it to a room that you will use is still not a good choice.

Apart from the background temperature of the space on whatever a hot day is in your mild climate, have you considered how you will deal with the heat this will be pumping out continuously when you've loaded it up with 70 KG of stuff that uses power?

As for mounting it, either drill into the masonry wall and use appropriate masonry anchors and bolts, or put planks across the framing it's sitting next to and use lag bolts. If planks on the front of the framing would upset your finishing plans, mount a plank (roughly 37mm or 1.5 inch thick) between framing members to be behind the finish layer you plan, and get that finish layer (or a piece of plywood the same thickness as your planned finish layer) in place behind the rack, before mounting it.

Comment: I agree with mounting lumber to the truss uprights. I would not modify those other than to run a few construction screws into them. Don't drill for lag screws or make any cuts.

Comment: I quadruple the "it's to hot in the attic" sentiments! Heat is the #1 enemy of computers. About the only way I'd consider putting it in the attic is if I had an AC duct nearby that I could tap into for a flow of nice ice-cold air in the summer directed directly into the bottom of the rack. Of course that would need to be _thoroughly_ sealed off in the winter because you don't want to be pumping heat in there during the winter.

Comment: @FreeMan  Too MUCH heat is an enemy of computers.  Google runs their server rooms at 80 degrees F to save on cooling costs. Servers don't last longer at 70 degrees than at 80.   https://www.airpacinc.com/new-blog/bid/83313/how-google-saved-1-billion-dollars-in-data-center-cooling-costs

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Google has minions carefully monitoring and maintaining 80° in their rack rooms. That is _much_ different than 120°+ unmonitored in the attic where one tends to forget all about it until the software kicks in to slow things down or shut them down due to overheating - if one _has_ temperature monitoring software running on the boxen to shut things down. Additionally, with the exception of _extreme_ cold possibly interfering with the operation of mechanical hard drives, the colder and drier, the better.

Comment: @FreeMan  No disagreement here, attics are the worst place for servers as you rightly pointed out, they get extremely hot.  My only point is you don't have to run them at 68 or 70. 80 degrees F is safe.

Answer (score 0):

All that wood is oversized (this is how buildings are designed), making 6mm holes for lag bolts, coach bolts, or structural screws will not compromise the structure significantly.

Others have suggested that it may be too hot in the attic, adding a vent to the roof
will help, then adding a duct from the eaves to the server cabinet will then feed outside air to the cabinet which should keep the temperature in the cabinet down.

Comment: While the concept of roof venting isn't new and random water ingress in to the house is generally considered a Bad Thing™ and methods for ensuring no water ingress are well known, water ingress expressly directed toward computer hardware is an Exceedingly Bad Thing™. _Extreme_ care must be taken to ensure that any roof venting leading from a server rack directly outside is very waterproof. A small leak will take a fair bit of time before it has a negative impact on the house structure. A small leak will have rather _immediate_ negative impact on computer infrastructure.